# How do you configure VSCode to open a given file type in an external editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my current specific case, I'm trying to open a `.po` file with Poedit. I will also likely want to open `.psd` files with Photoshop, and `.svg` files with Illustrator.

I suspect I'm still missing the proper term to search. I've found a reference to `launch.json` (which I think is for configuring external debugging?) but have yet to find that, much less my current goal of "Let me double click a PO and open it in Poedit!"

Comment: I've found `sandcastle.vscode-open` which provides an "Open with External Editor" contextual item. So far, that's what I'm using. Any other solutions out there?

Comment: closely related question for if you want to open with the default application configured at the OS/desktop-env level: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72130168/11107541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** This seems not to be possible currently (see also https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-open-in-application/issues/9).

**Orignal answer:**

You could try this extension: [Open in Application](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-open-in-application)

Comment: That's a step up from "Open with External Editor" since I can configure it. However, double clicking a file with a mapped extension still opens it in VSCode.

Comment: And apparently, mapping a double click to an external editor is not possible. Many thanks for the reply. :-D

Comment: I assume you refer to this issue of "Open in Application": https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-open-in-application/issues/9 Yeah, it is a pity, but maybe the VSC team extends its API. I will update my answer. Thanks for accepting it anyway, although it doesn't really helps you. :-)

Comment: Yes. The very thing that made me step back from my "What, I can't have flowers?" point of view. Plus, the accept and further discussion keeps the next person from wondering where the same solution is.

Answer (score 2):

I found this extension: [Open in External App](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YuTengjing.open-in-external-app) by [YuTengjing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/YuTengjing). Once installed, I can open the asset in the specified app by us. I really like the option where I can open a file in multiple apps at once (eg. open an html file in Chrome, Firefox and Edge for cross-browser testing).

Answer (score 0):

As @josh1978 said [Open in External App](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YuTengjing.open-in-external-app) by [YuTengjing](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/YuTengjing) works well and mostly solves the problem.

However, it has some problems in a WSL2 environment because the substitution variables for  the current `${file}` interprets the text `\r`, `\c` as control characters and the path includes the full WSL path I.E. `wsl.host\Ubuntu\home...`

To get it to work you have to play some games with the shell command to coerce the path to what is needed. Here' is a configuration that will launch lbreoffice for powerpoint and excel files.

```
"openInExternalApp.openMapper": {
  "extensionName": "pptx",
  "apps": [{
    "title": "libreoffice", 
    "shellCommand": "bash -c 'file=\"${file}\";libreoffice \"${file/*Ubuntu/}\"' " 
  }]
},
{
  "extensionName": "xlsx",
  "apps": [{
    "title": "libreoffice", 
    "shellCommand": "bash -c 'file=\"${file}\";libreoffice \"${file/*Ubuntu/}\"' "
  }]
}
```

To explain a bit of what this does. It executes the command as bash (instead of sh) so it can use bash parameter expansion to search/replace portions of the string.

Next it assigns `{file}` to itself which corrects the `\r \c` issues.

Lastly it strips off the leading part of the full path up to and including the 'Ubuntu' leaving the path in the form `\home\{user}\...` which will get interpreted correctly despite having `\` instead of `/`.