# Can VS Code open files with external programs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way to set VS Code such that double-clicking a .docx file in the embedded file explorer causes the file to be opened in Microsoft Word?

I'm used to PyCharm but I've been migrating to VS Code. I'm used to creating Word document files (.docx) and double-clicking them in the file explorer on the left side sub-window to launch Word and see what the document looks like. This works in PyCharm, but in VS Code it tries to open the file as a binary and claims it has no editor. Even if it did had an editor, I wanted it to open in my second monitor (or at least to be able to move it to my second monitor). For the time being, I'm opening a file explorer window and double clicking the file there, which has been less than optimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you configure VSCode to open a given file type in an external editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803500/how-do-you-configure-vscode-to-open-a-given-file-type-in-an-external-editor)

Comment: @starball a much older post whose first answer says it is not possible does  answer my question. And this question already has an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get this question merged with that one for the benefit of future readers and searchers. It's usually recommended to first close as a duplicate before merging. merging causes the answers from both questions to be visible in the same page. "does this answer your question" is (unfortunately) the standard text for auto-posted comments when duplicate-flagging. The real determiner of whether something is a duplicate or not is whether the questions are the same. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/997587

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not quite double clicking, but you could create an open file command as a task, then bind that task to a keyboard shortcut, which amounts to one click and one hotkey.

### Creating the open file task

We preferably make this task user-level, so that is accessible in every project.

`ctrl+shift+p` and search `Tasks: Open User Tasks`

In the `tasks.json` file, add the open file task to the `tasks` array:

```json
// Inside "tasks": [ ... ]
{
  "label": "open file",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "${file}",
  "presentation": {
  // Hides the task terminal from showing up
    "reveal": "never",
  }
}
```

Change the `"command"` to whatever the open file command for your shell is (just `${file}` works for windows, but change it to `xdg-open ${file}` for linux)

### Assigning a keybinding to the open file task

To bind the task command to a keybinding, `ctrl+shift+p` and search `keyboard shortcuts (JSON)`, open the file. Add the following to the array (changing `"key"` to whatever combination you desire)

```json
// [ ... ]
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "open file"
}
```

To open any file, click on it to focus it in a tab (which sets the `${file}` defined in `tasks.json`) and use the assigned hotkey. (As a side note, opening files that have vscode as their default program will open it in the same instance, so it makes it seem like the task isn't doing anything)

Comment: This works, and as far as I've searched, I've found no better solution/idea.

Comment: The fact that this BASIC feature of other editors isn't present in vscode is blowing my mind. How is this not a bigger problem for people?

Comment: I don't want to set up and memorize a shortcut key for a feature i don't use everyday. If i use "run user task" then nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

There's an app for that :)

If you install the extension "Open in External App" you can right click on file and chose "Open in External App" and, e.g. Word, will open the file.

[image: VS Code Extenssion]

Answer (score 1):

To work, Windows users should take care with command quotes

`tasks.json` :

```
{
    "label": "open file",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "'c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE' '${file}'"
}
```