# How can I add to the list of options in the "Open With..." menu of VS Code's Explorer View

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the same question as [reddit post "Adding a 'default editor'?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/z6uazq/adding_a_default_editor/) The question surfaces in multiple contexts where Visual Studio Code (VS Code) prompts `Select editor for...` Perhaps the easiest illustration is when, in the VS Code **Explorer**, you right click a file and choose `Open With...` VS Code responds with a dialog that prompts `Select editor for...` and below that text is a list of editors to choose from. Question is, how do you add editors to that list?

Searching for answers is difficult because the associated terms result in many 'hits' that have nothing to do with this specific question.

Comment: Do you have an extension installed that supplies a custom editor?  I beleive those are what would automatically give you options in the `Select editor...` input.  I tested with the `Luna Paint - Image` extension and that is how it worked.

Comment: That's likely true @Mark. However, it isn't what I wish to do. I want to use my preferred editor with a specific file type (extension).

Comment: it might be too late, but i found a workaround by using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YuTengjing.open-in-external-app

Answer (score 1):

From my research, both the "Open With..." menu from the Explorer View's list item context menu, and the menu from the `View: Reopen Editor With...` command's menu show an item to open with the default VS Code, text editor one to configure a default, and **the rest (if any) come from custom editors contributed by extensions**, which you can read more about in [the Custom Editor API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors). Of note from those docs:

> - `displayName` - Name that identifies the custom editor in VS Code's UI.
>
>   The display name is shown to the user in VS Code UI such as the **View: Reopen with dropdown**.

So if you want to add something to it, write an extension which contributes a custom editor.

I kind of get the feeling that you were looking for something different- a way to add an option to open something in an application *external* to VS Code- but from my (extremely limited and very possibly wrong) understanding of what this feature is, this feature does not enable you to do that. For that, you should instead see [Can vscode open files with external programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68629811/11107541) / [How do you configure VSCode to open a given file type in an external editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58803500/11107541).

Note that if you want to add things to menus in VS Code, usually a good first place to look is https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points.