# How to let VS Code open file using the default program of the operating system?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the latest `VS Code` to write python Qt code (under Ubuntu 20.04). One obstacle is that VS code does not recognize known file types such as `.ui` files, and opens it as *raw* text or xml file.

By comparison, other editors such as `eclipse` opens the `.ui` file with its OS default program -- Qt Designer. With VS Code, I had to open a file manager and then find and double-click the file to open it the right way (the same as opening the file using `xdg-open` in terminal), which is quite inefficient.

*Does anyone know of a way to configure VS code to open a known file directly using its OS default program?*

Answer (score 5):

There are two extensions that I know of that tackle this problem (no affiliation):

- [Open in External App](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YuTengjing.open-in-external-app)

> ... with this extension, you can do it more simply. Just right click to the file, and select Open in External App, that file would be opened by system default application. You can also use this way to open .psd files with photoshop, .html files with browser, and so on...

The configuration implies that you need to manually set which app to use for which extension, so it doesn't simply use the default configured in your OS (at least not in my brief test).

- [Open](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sandcastle.vscode-open)

> Opens files using the OS's default program for the file type

This does what it says out of the box, but the keyboard shortcut seems to fail. The command can only be triggered via the right-click menu of the file in the vscode file browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are extensions which actually add menu items to the Explorer context menu, but just for fun, I decided to see how far I could get with builtin VS Code functionality.

The following approach defines a keybinding that you can use when a file or folder is selected in VS Code's File Explorer subview. It copies its path, and then runs a command in the integrated terminal to open it with the system's default application for that type of file. It has a timing issue related to pasting where it doesn't work if an integrated terminal isn't already open (and trying to make it open/focus the integrated terminal as part of the command sequence also doesn't work). You'd paste this into your keybindings.json file, which you can open using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO pick something
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "copyFilePath",
            // "terminal.focus",
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": { "text": "start '" }, // or `open` on macOS, or `xdg-open` or `open` on Linux
                // You can be extra fancy once VS Code 1.86 releases, where commands in arguments of `runCommands` can have their own when-clauses (see context keys `isWindows`, `isMac`, `isLinux`).
            },
            "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": { "text": "'\n" },
            },
        ],
    },
    "when": "filesExplorerFocus && listHasSelectionOrFocus && resourceSet && isFileSystemResource",
},
```

See also:

- https://superuser.com/q/550138/1749748
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212583/479746
- https://askubuntu.com/q/15354/1624654